# Using PHP to re-render PNG-24 to PNG-8 on browsers?

Tags: php, png

Is there a PHP function which can accept the image path of a PNG-24 as a parameter and then return a PNG-8 version on web browsers?

For example, the HTML code of the original PNG-24 is:

`<img src="image/path/lorem.png">`

And then this will return a PNG-8 version on web browsers:

`<img src="convert-png24-to-pnp8.php?image/path/lorem.png">`

The PNG-24 images I want to convert don't have semi-transparent pixels but has completely transparent pixels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on SERPRO’s answer above, using ImageMagick you could do something like:

```
$image = new Imagick("mypng24.png");
$image->setImageFormat("png8");
header( "Content-Type: image/png" );
echo $image;
```

That’s untested, but should give you something to go on. The formats ImageMagick can export as are listed here: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the image with [ImageMagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php).

Transform PNG-24 into PNG-8: http://www.whoisgregg.com/imagemagick/index.html

Comment: Thanks. Among so many classes in the first link, I didn't find a class for converting to PNG-8. Could you point it out for me?

Answer (score 0):

If you can call out to shell then you could use `pngquant` to do the job. That’ll (batch) convert PNG-24s into PNG-8s for you.

http://pngquant.org/

Comment: Thanks. However, this method is currently beyond my ability.

Comment: OK, looks like ImageMagick it is then. I’ll add another answer with sample code.